# Detect pixel collision/overlapping between two images

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, transparency, collision-detection

I have two UIImageViews that contain images with some transparent area.  Is there any way to check if the non-transparent area between both images collide?

Thanks.

[UPDATE]
So this is what I have up until now, unfortunately it still ain't working but I can't figure out why.

```
if (!CGRectIntersectsRect(frame1, frame2)) return NO;
NSLog(@"OverlapsPixelsInImage:withImage:> Images Intersect");

UIImage *img1 = imgView1.image;
UIImage *img2 = imgView2.image;
CGImageRef imgRef1 = [img1 CGImage];
CGImageRef imgRef2 = [img2 CGImage];

float minx = MIN(frame1.origin.x, frame2.origin.x);
float miny = MIN(frame1.origin.y, frame2.origin.y);
float maxx = MAX(frame1.origin.x + frame1.size.width, frame2.origin.x + frame2.size.width);
float maxy = MAX(frame1.origin.y + frame1.size.height, frame2.origin.y + frame2.size.height);
CGRect canvasRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, maxx - minx, maxy - miny);

size_t width = floorf(canvasRect.size.width);
size_t height = floorf(canvasRect.size.height);

NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
NSUInteger bytesPerRow = 4 * width;
unsigned char *rawData = calloc(width * height, sizeof(*rawData));
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, width, height, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, canvasRect.size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

CGContextClipToMask(context, CGRectMake(frame2.origin.x - minx, frame2.origin.y - miny, frame2.size.width, frame2.size.height), imgRef2);
CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(frame1.origin.x - minx, frame1.origin.y - miny, frame1.size.width, frame1.size.height), imgRef1);

CGContextRelease(context);

int byteIndex = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < width * height; i++)
{
    CGFloat alpha = rawData[byteIndex + 3];
    if (alpha > 128) 
    {
        NSLog(@"collided in byte: %d", i);
        free(rawData);
        return YES;
    }
    byteIndex += 4;
}

free(rawData);

return NO;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw both the alpha channels of both images into a single bitmap context and then look through the data for any transparent pixels. Take a look at the `clipRectToPath()` code in [Clipping CGRect to a CGPath](http://robnapier.net/blog/clipping-cgrect-cgpath-531). It's solving a different problem, but the approach is the same. Rather than using `CGContextFillPath()` to draw into the context, just draw both of your images.

Here's the flow:

1. Create an alpha-only bitmap context (`kCGImageAlphaOnly`)
2. Draw everything you want to compare into it
3. Walk the pixels looking at the value. In my example, it considers `< 128` to be "transparent." If you want fully transparent, use `== 0`.
4. When you find a transparent pixel, the example just makes a note of what column it was in. In your problem, you might just return `YES`, or you might use that data to form another mask.

Comment: I don't understand yet how this algorithm detects collision.  It is obvious to me that I will find transparent and non-transparent pixels if I draw both images in a kCGImageAlphaOnly context so looking for transparent pixels won't do the trick.

Comment: You're correct. I don't believe you can merge the images easily here to find overlap (I was looking for transparency). @logancautrell's approach should work correctly, though. Use the reference sample to create two bitmap arrays, and then walk them both looking for `X>0 && Y>0`.

Comment: Maybe your method works too.  You could draw one image to mask the other.  Then if there's any non-transparent pixel it would mean that there's collision.

Comment: I keep going over this in my head, and you should be right. I always have to play with these a bit and sketch them out on paper to keep them straight in my head.

Answer (score 1):

Not easily, you basically have to read the in raw bitmap data and walk the pixels.